# AngularJS directive append a tablerow from one table to another table

Tags: angularjs, append, tablerow, directive

I'm working with AngularJS at the moment and in my current Project i've got to append a row from table1(in which a button is clicked by a user) to a 2nd table. On top of this the button also has to perform a $http.post(...).

So what i got is a table with data populated by ng-repeat and in one of the td's i have a button with the ng-click directive which executes a function with a $http.post.

**html:**

```
<table id="tableOne">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="source">
    <tr ng-cloak ng-repeat="person in persons">
        <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.age }}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="movePerson(person.id)">Move to 2nd Table</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click on the Button the function "movePerson(person.id) in my Controller will be called and that works fine.

**controller:**

```
$scope.movePerson = function ( id ) {

    DataService.movePerson( id, { result: function ( data, status ) {
        if( data.success === true )
        {
            $log.log( "person has been moved" );
        }
    }, fault: function ( data, status ) {
            $log.log( "an error has occured" );
    } } );
};
```

'DataService' is handling my $http requests.

Now I want to move the tablerow where the button was clicked to another table(id="tableTwo") with tbody id="target".
I've read you shouldn't use jQuery in your Controller.. so is there an "angular-way" to do this? Because i would like to not include jQuery at all in my Project.

I thought you would use a directive for these kind of things, so that you can just add the directive in the button tag like the "ng-click" like this:

```
<td><button ng-click="movePerson(person.id)" move-tbl-row>Move to 2nd Table</button></td>
```

But since i'm new to Angular i don't know how my directive would look like. And will the "ng-click" still be executed then?

Geetings and Thanks.

Comment: You could handle the entire process from within your directives linking function, so ng-click won't be necessary anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking how to move the row ....thinking like jQuery....when in fact you want to change the array the data object is in.

Here's a slight modification for you.

```
<!-- pass whole object into scope function -->
<button ng-click="movePerson(person)">Move to 2nd Table</button>
```

```js
$scope.movePerson = function ( person ) {
   var id= person.id;
    /* on ajax success, remove from persons array */
    var idx= $scope.persons.indexOf(person);
    $scope.persons.splice(idx,1);
    /* add person object to another scope array*/
     $scope.another_array.push(person);


})
```

Comment: Thanks this works, the "..thinking like jQuery.." words helped a lot. No idea why i didn't think of this. And there's a little typo in your answer if you want to correct it, it should be `$scope.persons.splice(idx,1);`